# High revs after changing spark plugs

Tags: sparkplugs, chrysler, town-and-country, fast-idle

I have an '07 Chrysler Town & Country.

Check Engine Light came on 2 weeks ago, ran the diagnostics : Misfire in cylinder 3.

So we changed the spark plug in that cylinder to see if that was the issue and it was. Since you are supposed to change all of them and not just one, this weekend we changed the other 5.

Now it is reving too high and accelerates without pressing the gas. It gets up to 20 miles per hour before it levels off.

It is also difficult to brake, the pedal is stiff. Any suggestions as to what it might be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You mention two issues:

- fast idle
- hard brakes

Both of these point to a vacuum leak.

Inspect the brake booster vacuum line; it might have been compromised during the spark plug swap.

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly it; hose was completely off.

Comment: @MelissaCooleyLake you're welcome! Your great level of detail on the question was key